# How to add a notice/alert to a before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, alert, before-filter

So I have a before filter like the following when using devise:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :destroy, :edit, :update]
```

So whenever I go to the new action I an redirected to users_sign_in route if I am not signed in. However the user might be confused and would like to know why they are being redirected there when they intended to use the new action.

How can I add a message or an alert to a before filter that shows up only if there is a redirect...

Something like:

```
notice: 'You must sign in before creating a new product!'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a better solution while testing different things. I think it's simpler and more intuitive:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :destroy, :edit, :update], notice: 'you must sign in first!'
```

Comment: This looks very elegant, but I can't get it to work - any pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
flash[:notice] = 'You must sign in before creating a new product!'
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html

Remember to display flashes in your layout file.
See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash